# MediaWiki: changing the label of a category at the bottom of the page

Tags: mediawiki, categories

In **mediawiki**, is it possible to change the label of a 'Category' at the bottom of an article.

For example for the following article:

```
=Paris=
blablablablablabla

[[Category:place_id]]
```

I'd like to see something more verbose like (the example below doesn't work):

```
=Paris=
blablablablablabla

[[Category:place_id|France]]
```

Note: I don't want to use a 'redirect' and I want to keep my strange ids because they are linked to an external database.

Comment: I don't think you can do this in the default package. You would have to find an extension to do this or build one yourself. The bit of the category link after the | is the [sort key](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Categories#Sort_key). It defines how the page is sorted in the list of pages belonging to the category.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think mediawiki is supporting this feature. 
However, how about using:

```
[[Category:France]]
```

in your page, and set it into the category named with your id? France would just be a subcategory of "place_id", and you could use more terms all linked to the parent category. For this, you just need to edit the category page for "France", inserting:

```
[[Category:place_id]]
```

An alternative would be to put your page in both categories, but in this case, the id would still be displayed:

```
[[Category:place_id]]
[[Category:France]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with an [`OutputPageMakeCategoryLinks` hook](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aHooks/OutputPageMakeCategoryLinks).  Alas, the interface for that hook seems to be a bit inconvenient — as far as I can tell, it's pretty much only good for replacing the standard category link generation code entirely.  Still, you *could* do that is you want:

```php
function myOutputPageMakeCategoryLinks( &$out, $categories, &$links ) {
    foreach ( $categories as $category => $type ) {
        $title = Title::makeTitleSafe( NS_CATEGORY, $category );
        $text = $title->getText();
        if ( $text == 'Place id' ) {
            // set $text to something else
        }
        $links[$type][] = Linker::link( $title, htmlspecialchars( $text ) );
    }
    return false;  // skip default link generation
}
$wgHooks['OutputPageMakeCategoryLinks'][] = 'myOutputPageMakeCategoryLinks';
```

(The code above is based on the default category link generation code in [OutputPage.php](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/gitweb?p=mediawiki/core.git;a=blob;f=includes/OutputPage.php), somewhat simplified; I assume you're not using [language variant conversion](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Writing_systems#LanguageConverter) on your wiki, so I removed the parts that deal with that.  Note that **this code is untested!**  Use at your own risk.)